# Is there a way to pull failure logs from testing stage via api?

Tags: go-cd

I am attempting to pull test failures from gocd via the apis to be able to track the brittleness of our integration tests. I have looked at the gocd api documentation and only found a way to pull the failure stages of a particular job. I want to however be able to pull the failure logs of the failed stages. Is there any way to do this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

This is on gocd version 17.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

A stage fails if any of its jobs fails. So stages don't have failure logs on their own, you have to descend into the jobs and their logs (and possibly artifacts).